# Getting total out of sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database (sqlite on Android) with several columns:
_id, datum, hour, note

The database is created by this:

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table worked (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "datum text not null, hour text not null, " 
    + "note text);";
```

At the end I want the total of hours and minutes out of my database and return it to my mainActivity.

I tried to do this:

```
public int getTotalHours(){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select hour from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
    int total = 0;
    Date hours = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    c.moveToFirst();
    for(int i = 0; i<c.getCount(); i++){
        String uur = c.getString(i);
        try {
            hours = hourFormat.parse(uur);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        total += hours.getHours();
    }
    return total;
}
```

But I'm already getting a error in my query. I also dont know how if the data is being extracted at the right way, I cant test that because of the query error...

The error I'm getting:

> Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a cursorWindow which has 5 rows, 1 columns.

I hope I was in the right way, and that somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQLite rows start off at 1 if I'm not mistaken, try 1 instead of i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly loop through your records, retrieve the proper column index, and close your cursor:

```
public int getTotalHours(){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select hour from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
    if (c == null)
        return 0;

    try{
        int total = 0;
        Date hours = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            String uur = c.getString(0);
            try {
                hours = hourFormat.parse(uur);
                total += hours.getHours();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }

        return hours;
    }finally{
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This has solved my problem! I understand your solution now also, I'll use it again later :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you need help understanding it let me know.

Answer (score 0):

use

String uur = c.getString(1);

Comment: If I use that then I would get the data from _id 1 all the time, I have to get the total of the hours from all of the entries. Not just that only 1. I did set the i to 1, but then I also got the error I already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, start your int i off at 1 instead of 0

```
for(int i = 1; i<c.getCount(); i++){
    String uur = c.getString(i);
    try {
        hours = hourFormat.parse(uur);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Tried it, this error again: Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a cursorWindow which has 5 rows, 1 columns.

Comment: Ok, could you plz post the logCat?

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a table in a database what you are creating so I suggest you use `CREATE_TABLE` variable name instead.
Second, you can do:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select sum(hour) from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
```

having defined `hour` as integer in you table.

If you define the correct columns and use the right operations sqlite can do it:

```
sqlite> .schema t1
CREATE TABLE t1 (hours time not null);
sqlite> select * from t1;
05:30:00
06:30:00
01:30:00
02:15:00
sqlite> select strftime('%H:%M', 946684800 + sum(strftime('%s', hours) - 946684800), 'unixepoch') from t1;
15:45
sqlite>
```

Comment: I can't because I used Strings in my database, just because its in the format HH:MM.

Answer (score 0):

Calling c.moveToNext() at the end of the loop would help. Also c.getString(i) should be c.getString(0).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the hours row is the first one in the db table. if you're not sure this modified code should work

```
enter code here
public int getTotalHours(){
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select hour from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
int total = 0;
Date hours = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
c.moveToFirst();
int column = c.getColumnIndex("id")
for(int i = 0; i<c.getCount(); i++){
    String uur = c.getString(c);
    try {
        hours = hourFormat.parse(uur);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    total += hours.getHours();
}
return total;
```

}